# CSS Adaptive Styling - Add scrolling to a sidebar without a defined height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height, overflow

I'm creating a basic web app which contains a sidebar that is sized vertically by how many elements are in it.

I want the web-app to have adaptive sizing, so will work on any size device.

When the user shrinks the viewport vertically and some of the elements within the sidebar overflow the viewport, I want the sidebar to shrink not overflowing the viewport, and allow scrolling of its contents.

The sidebar is not a predefined height (eg. 50% or 700px), as it is determined by how many elements are within it (could be 3, could be 30).

The image below is the best way I can visualise what I am looking to do:

[CSS example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlwTx.png)

White: is the viewport

Light Blue: is the sidebar

Dark Blue: is the elements inside sidebar

Grey: is the scrollbar

I can get this to work when the sidebar is a predefined height by using `overflow: auto`, but cannot get this to work when I do not define the height of the sidebar, and leave it to the child elements to determine its height.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use overflow-y: auto to parent

Comment: I can't get this to work as the height is not defined in the parent element, is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If i can understand true, you can use calc() function in your css.

eg: 
If you show 5 element on viewport(height), you can use this code for element style:

`height: calc(100vh/5)`

this code means: Divide the entire apparent height by 5.

eg: https://jsfiddle.net/uniak/rgzf9nmy/

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for - the sidebar itself is not defined in terms of the viewport, but the content inside of it. So it could be 800px in height, and when this goes off the screen, I want to still be able to see the content, so add a scroll.

The 800px is ambiguous however, one time it may be 300px, another it may be 600px !